# ClojureScript REPL with node-webkit

Tags: clojurescript, node-webkit

Is it possible to connect a ClojureScript REPL to a node-webkit application

My cljs code is as simple as:

```
(ns webkit-test.core
  (:require [clojure.browser.repl :as repl]))


(repl/connect "http://localhost:9000/repl")
```

And the corresponding html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>

        <script src="out/goog/base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="out/webkit_test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">goog.require("webkit_test.core");</script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Then launching a REPL as follows

```
 lein trampoline cljsbuild repl-listen
```

hangs when I try to evaluate a form such as `(+ 1 1)`

I was following the [moderncljs](https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs) tutorial and I can connect via the REPL when I host the html page via an http server, but when it's hosted in node-webkit it doesn't work for me. Are there some tricks I can use to make it work? I was able to connect to node-webkit via the script-tag in LightTable, but this would mean that I have to use LightTable for the REPL (which might be okay sometimes). I would just like to have a plain vanilla leinigen ClojureScript REPL that talks to my node-webkit app. I had a look at this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/light-table-discussion/Z3nM3pXIpBs) but that didn't help.

Comment: I get the same error as described in this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/BQa9WkRvloo (Uncaught Error: URI file:/robots.txt is invalid for field ppu). The reason is given as: "The REPL will not work with mixed protocols". Does it mean that I can forget about connecting the REPL to node webkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with trying to connect to a ClojureScript REPL from non-HTTP contexts, so I wrote a simple REPL server and client that communicates over WebSockets rather than HTTP/iframe messages.

https://github.com/tomjakubowski/weasel

I'm not familiar with Node WebKit, but presumably you can connect a REPL from your page this way.